# Security Exception while Exporting contacts to SD card

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I'm trying to Export contacts to SD card by passing package name to Intent like below

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.contacts",
                    "com.android.contacts.ExportVCardActivity"));
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

But its giving following exception in galaxy Ace and S2 (i tried only on these devices)

> 11-04 12:37:05.808: W/System.err(3461): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.contacts/.ExportVCardActivity } from ProcessRecord{40710c10 3461:com.ImpExp/10060} (pid=3461, uid=10060) requires null
>   11-04 12:37:05.816: W/System.err(3461):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1322)
>   11-04 12:37:05.820: W/System.err(3461):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
>   11-04 12:37:05.820: W/System.err(3461):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1351)
>   11-04 12:37:05.824: W/System.err(3461):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1374)
>   11-04 12:37:05.828: W/System.err(3461):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
>   11-04 12:37:05.832: W/System.err(3461):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
>   11-04 12:37:05.832: W/System.err(3461):     at com.ImpExp.ImpExp$4.onClick(ImpExp.java:74)
>   11-04 12:37:05.832: W/System.err(3461):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
>   11-04 12:37:05.832: W/System.err(3461):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
>   11-04 12:37:05.832: W/System.err(3461):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>   11-04 12:37:05.832: W/System.err(3461):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   11-04 12:37:05.832: W/System.err(3461):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>   11-04 12:37:05.832: W/System.err(3461):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>   11-04 12:37:05.832: W/System.err(3461):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   11-04 12:37:05.832: W/System.err(3461):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   11-04 12:37:05.835: W/System.err(3461):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   11-04 12:37:05.835: W/System.err(3461):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>   11-04 12:37:05.835: W/System.err(3461):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

i given

> android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" and
>   android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

Even though its crashing, any idea what exactly i need to permission or any other way also appreciated.

Comment: probably it is no a solution but try to add the permission WRITE_CONTACTS.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to declare the activity on the manifest.xml file?